# $f_n(x_n) \rightarrow f(x) $ by uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am very nearly done with this problem, but I have a concern that someone must help me alleviate.

> Suppose $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, $f_n$ are continuous,  and $x_n\rightarrow x$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x_n) =f(x) .$$

We want to use $$|f_n(x_n) - f(x) |\leq |f_n(x_n) - f_n(x) |+|f_n(x) - f(x) |.$$ 
At first, I let $N$ be a number so that $n\geq N$ implied that $|f_n(x) - f(x) |< \epsilon /2$ for any $x$. Now,  since $f_n$ is continuous, $\lim_{m\to\infty} f_n(x_m) =f_n(x) $, we can take $|f_n(x_m) - f_n(x) |<\epsilon /2$ for $m$ greater than some $M$. But, can we take $|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x) |<\epsilon /2$? Maybe not,  if $n<M$. We could insist this is not true, and take $n$ to be greater than $M$ by WLOG letting $N$ get larger. But since we defined $M$ in the context of a particular $f_n$, now $M$ might be different,  so we are going in a circle. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hmph, originally I was thinking of some slick answer (to which now I realize it's meant for something else) to the question. But I see Joshua's initial answer had disappeared, are you still having issues?

Comment: @Nameless Yeah. I can't figure out why it would be a problem if $|f_n(x_n) - f_n(x) |\geq \epsilon/2$ for every $n$.

Comment: wait why would you want that to happen?

Comment: @Nameless I don't. I want to prove it leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Why can't you take $n > \max\{ N, M\}$? If, following your idea, how would you handle $|f_n - f|$?

Comment: I think its easier to start with the slightly different form: $|f_n(x_n)-f(x)| \leq |f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)| + |f(x_n)-f(x)|$. The first term is bounded by $|f_n - f|_{\infty}$ and the second one by the continuity of $f$.

Comment: @Nameless because I defined $M$ after picking a particular $n$. If I were to use your $N^\prime$ then maybe it would be bigger than $n$, in which case we would need to get a new $n$ to get a new $M$,  which might then be bigger and require we get an $N^{\prime\prime} $, etc. Etc. It would be circular.

Comment: @Winther why should $\left|f_n-f\right|_\infty$ be finite?

Comment: That is the definition of uniform convergence: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_x|f_n(x) - f(x)| = 0$

Comment: @TheWhiteQueen, you don't pick $n$, the little $n$.

Comment: Read [Bartle](https://matstkipbjm.files.wordpress.com/2011/03/bartle_introduction-to-real-analysis-new-edition.pdf) exercise 8.2.4, p. 238 and the hint, p. 372 .

Comment: [Exercise 9.4.11](https://books.google.it/books?id=vA9d57GxCKgC&pg=PA386&lpg=PA386&dq=%22continuous+convergence%22+vs+uniform&source=bl&ots=KQ1fKm6OQo&sig=Rr-f1N_7Vh3uRJgqLJGv-mbx2h4&hl=it&sa=X&ei=oNu_VMGWH8HTaN_rgfAK&ved=0CGEQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=%22continuous%20convergence%22%20vs%20uniform&f=false) can be interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will give a proof using a slightly different version of the triangle inequality than the one used by OP namely

$$|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| \leq |f_n(x_n) - f(x_n)| + |f(x_n) - f(x)|$$

We start off by fixing $\epsilon > 0$. From the definition of uniform convergence there exist a $N$ s.t. if $n>N$ the first term is less than $\epsilon / 2$.

The uniform convergence of $f_n\to f$ and the fact that $f_n$ is continuous it follows that $f$ is continuous. This implies that there exist a $\delta>0$ s.t. if $|x-x_n|<\delta$ then $|f(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon/2$. Finally since $x_n\to x$ there exist a $M$ s.t. if $n>M$ we have $|x-x_n| < \delta$.

Putting it all togeather we find that if $n>\text{max}(N,M)$ then

$$|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon$$