# Prove $f_n(x_n) \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $(f_n)_n$ be a sequence of real-valued functions on $E$, a subset of a metric space $X$.  Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $E$ and assume that $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E$.  Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $E$ such that $f(x_n) \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$.  Prove that $f_n(x_n) \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$.

I want to make an effort at proving this, but I am struggling with the definitions.  I know that

$f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E$ means $\forall \epsilon >0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n\geq N: \forall x \in E: |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.

The parts I am struggling to write are the logical statements for

$f(x_n) \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow\infty \ \ $  (Perhaps $\forall \epsilon >0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n\geq N: |f(x_n) - L| < \epsilon \ $?)

and

$f_n(x_n) \rightarrow L$ as $n \rightarrow\infty$.

I do want to give this a genuine try (even if I will probably need help anyway; I'm terrible at analysis). If someone could help me with these definitions, I could at least update the question with an attempt at a solution and hopefully get help from there.

Comment: Uniform convergence is a property of a sequence of *functions* so you need to omit the argument $x_n$ of $f_n$ when speaking about uniform convergence (twice).

Comment: And I confirm the "Perhaps".

Comment: @Justpassingby: I'm confused.  Which $x_n$'s do I need to omit?  I'm assuming you're talking about the first of the three definitions, but the only $x_n$ that I see is the one copied from the problem.

Comment: What I mean is that the statement "$f_n(x_n)\to f$ uniformly" is meaningless. It is the functions $f_n$ that converge uniformly, not their values at $x_n.$

Comment: @Justpassingby: Oh whoops.  I copied that incorrectly; I'll edit the question.  Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$f_n(x_n) \rightarrow f(x) $ by uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113165/f-nx-n-rightarrow-fx-by-uniform-convergence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prove $f_n(x_n)\to L$ which means

$$\forall\epsilon>0:\exists N\in\mathbb N:\forall n\geq N:|f_n(x_n)-L|<\epsilon.$$

We can prove this using the other two $\epsilon$-statements but we are not going to use the same $\epsilon$. Pick $N$ so large that certain quantities become sufficiently small to apply the triangle inequality and *still* remain less than $\epsilon.$

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  So from here, we can fix $\epsilon$ and pick $N_0$ to be the max $N$ from the other two $\epsilon$-statements, which forces $|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon /2$ and $|f(x_n) - L| < \epsilon /2$ for all $n \geq N_0$ and then apply the triangle inequality to $|f_n(x_n)-L|$.