# Uniform Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}, [0, 2\pi]$ by using Cauchy's test or Weierstrass-M test

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}, [0, 2\pi]$

---

I have been thinking for hours and I do not know how to approach whether it uniformly converges or not. Of course, I did search, but there was no desired result, and even if I found similar contents, it was difficult or unintelligible.

Is it possible to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}, [0, 2\pi]$ is whether uniform converges or not **by using Cauchy's test or Weierstrass-M test**?

I wait for an answer that will be clear and detailed. Please.

Thank you for reading so far and hope that today's good work will be full.

Comment: Weierstrass-M test doesn't work here. For $x=\pi/2$, $|\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{n}}| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n(x)$ denote partial sums of this infinite sum at $x$.
$$S_n(1/n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\sin(i/n)}{\sqrt{i}} = \sqrt{n}\cdot\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(i/n)}{\sqrt{i/n}} $$
Now
$$0\neq\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(i/n)}{\sqrt{i/n}} $$
where we used definition of Riemann integral.

Hence $$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n(1/n) = \infty \neq S(0) = 0 $$
This means that the convergence can't be uniform. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1113165/f-nx-n-rightarrow-fx-by-uniform-convergence) for more details.

This approach also shows, that we shouldn't expect uniform convergence of $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^a}$$
for $a<1$, $x$ is as earlier.

Indeed, for $0<a<1$ we have that
$$S_n(1/n) = n^{1-a}\cdot \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(i/n)}{(i/n)^a}$$
And
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\sin(i/n)}{(i/n)^a} = \int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x^a}dx>0 $$
Hence
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n(1/n) = \infty\neq S(0) = 0 $$
as a multiple of sequence converging to $\infty$ and to a finite non-zero number. So in this case, the sum isn't uniform convergent.